# Habilitar inicio de sesión con contraseña en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, seguridad

Estoy intentando hacer que Ubuntu me pida clave de inicio de sesión y no me hace caso a nada.

Intente modificar el siguiente archivo como se menciona en algunos foros: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` y lo que me aparece es lo siguiente:

```
[Seat:*]  
autologin-user=
```

En `Sistema => Cuentas de Usuario`, esta habilitada la opción de pedir contraseña.

Así y todo lo único que logro es que me muestre la pantalla de inicio de sesión pero no pide la clave.

Probe escribiendo en la consola `sudo passwd {USER}` y me pidio la clave, ademas de actualizar la clave para UNIX

Comment: Puedes poner el resto de los settings como estaban en tu lightdm.conf? No el archivo completo sino solamente las líneas que están junto a `autologin-user`

Comment: Eso es TODO lo que figura en el archivo. No omití nada.

Comment: Uh, pensé que habría otro setting que se podría tunear. Antes esa sección tenía 5 líneas, pero eso fue hace 4 años :(

Comment: Vi por algún foro el archivo con el formato en 5 lineas, lo escribí como lo describían ahí, y no modifico nada.

Answer (score 1):

Fijate si tu usuario pertenece al grupo "nopasswdlogin". Eso lo podés hacer ejecutando el comando `groups` que te imprime todos los grupos a los que pertenecés.
Si de hecho pertenecés a nopasswdlogin, para sacarte de ese grupo podés ejecutar `gpasswd -d <tu usuario> nopasswdlogin`.